# C++ - Extract string from comma separated float line

Tags: c++, regex, string, istringstream

I have a file with the following pattern: `0.123,0.432,0.123,ABC`

I've successfully retrieved the float numbers to an array, but I need now to find a way to get the last string. My code is the following:

```
    vector<float> test;
    for (float v = 0; test_ss >> v; ) {
        test.push_back(v);
        test_ss.ignore();
    }
```

Tips:

- As the number of elements in each line is known its not a problem
- Also I don't particularly need to use this structure, I was just using it because it was the best I've found so far.
- All I want is in the end to have a vector with the float elements and a string with that last field.

Comment: no i need only the string, but i'm new at c++ and i don't know how to do it using c++ (this is an requirement)

Comment: It seems you want to get the substring after the last `,`. A regex for this can be `[^,]+$`.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/KQXoGU

Comment: @GregórioGranadoMagalhães `std::regex` seems overkill to parse that.

Comment: I don't know a better way actually, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: The easiest approach is to read the known number of floats followed by reading the string: what exactly is your problem with doing so? Alternatively, read the line, find the last comma, and use the string starting after that (if it may contain commas just find the *n*th comma).

Comment: Yes, it's the easiest, but since it's an academic homework I think a more "advanced" approach would be "smarter" but if in the end I can't find another way that's what I'm going to do

Comment: Have you replace the commas with spaces?

Comment: I'm trying the following but it doesn't work: https://ideone.com/PSVo6X

Comment: Use [`s.substr(s.find_last_of(",") + 1)`](https://ideone.com/MxlAT7)

Comment: I can't modify the entry

Comment: @GregórioGranadoMagalhães use replace all

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `s.substr(s.find_last_of(",") + 1)` worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to first replace the string using `std::replace( test_ss.begin(), test_ss.end(), ',', ' ');` then to use your for loop:

```
vector<float> test;
for (float v = 0; test_ss >> v; ) {
    test.push_back(v);
    test_ss.ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RegEx` would be an overkill for this task, and `substr` will return `string` while you asked for `float` vector. I think what you need is to use `ifstream` and read comma into a dummy `char`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");

    std::vector<float> v(3);
    std::string s;
    char comma; // dummy

    if (ifs >> v[0] >> comma >> v[1] >> comma >> v[2] >> comma >> s)
    {
        for (auto i : v)
            std::cout << i << " -> ";

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
0.123 -> 0.432 -> 0.123 -> ABC
```